# Accessing intermediate results from a tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow

If I have a complex calculation of the form

```
tmp1 = tf.fun1(placeholder1,placeholder2)
tmp2 = tf.fun2(tmp1,placeholder3)
tmp3 = tf.fun3(tmp2)
ret  = tf.fun4(tmp3)
```

and I calculate

```
ret_vals = sess.run(ret,feed_dict={placeholder1: vals1, placeholder2: vals2, placeholder3: vals3})
```

fun1, fun2 etc are possibly costly operations on a lot of data.

If I run to get ret_vals as above, is it possible to later or at the same time access the intermediate values as well without re-running everything up to that value? For example, to get tmp2, I could re-run everything using

```
tmp2_vals = sess.run(tmp2,feed_dict={placeholder1: vals1, placeholder2: vals2, placeholder3: vals3})
```

But this looks like a complete waste of computation? Is there a way to access several of the intermediate results in a graph after performing one run?

The reason why I want to do this is for debugging or testing or logging of progress when ret_vals gets calculated e.g. in an optimization loop. Every step where I run the ret_vals calculations is costly but I want to see some of the intermediate results that were calculated.

If I do something like

```
tmp2_vals, ret_vals = sess.run([tmp2, ret], ...)
```

does this guarantee that the graph will only get run once (instead of one time for tmp2 and one time for ret) like I want it?

Comment: yes, the graph will only get run once in your second example

Comment: Is that the "standard way" of doing this then? Just return a long list of all the values we need?

Comment: Either that, or save them into tensorflow variable nodes to fetch later

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print)? This is an identity op with printing funciton. You can insert it in your graph right after tmp2 to get the value of it. Note that the default setting only allows you to print the first n values of the tensor, you can modify the value n by giving attribute `first_n` to the op.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed useful for some debugging tasks, but not so much if the values are needed for further processing/checking. 
So I guess that returning a list of values is probably the "standard" way of how to do this in TF, though I am not absolutely certain of that yet.